# NxBRE - Date Validation with the Flow Engine

Tags: nxbre

How to compare a date in `.xbre` rule file.

For example, I have the rule below:

```
<ObjectLookup id ="EmpObj" objectId ="EmpLvl" member ="JoinDate"/>
 <Logic>
    <If>
      <And>
        <Between leftId ="2009-10-10" rightId ="2010-10-10" valueId ="EmpObj">          
        </Between>
      </And>
      <Do>
        <Modify id ="LVL" type="String" value ="Sr"/>
      </Do>
    </If>
    <ElseIf>
      <And>
        <Between leftId ="2010-10-10" rightId ="2014-10-10" valueId ="EmpObj" excludeLeft ="true">
        </Between>
      </And>
      <Do>
        <Modify id ="LVL" type="String" value ="Jr"/>
      </Do>
    </ElseIf>
</Logic>
```

Based on the JoinDate passed, I need to get a string based on the date range. When I run the above rule, it takes the dates mentioned in `leftId` and `rightId` but does not take the date range.

How to check date range/between dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that the types are consistent across the board, ie that your either using `Strings` or `DateTime` types in both the value tested and the boundaries used in `Between`.

Comment: Thanks David, Specifying correct datatype resolved the issue.